# I want to make scroll bar be always visible in a div along with scroll bar thumb

Tags: html, css

I am implement loading on scroll on a div it works perfect but elements from it can be removed by user as well. I want that div to be always scrollable but if user removes element from it scroll bar dissappers.

I have tried `overflow-y: scroll` and have added height as well. it works: there is a scroll bar always visible but the scroll bar has no thumb which means that i cannot scroll either by mouse wheel or using the arrow on scrollbar.

So it would be great if someone can help me in making the scrollbar thumb always visible.

here is the div that i am talking about :

```
<div id="external-events" class="mt-actions" style="height: 530px; width: auto; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
```

[Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbXpr.png)

[scrollbar without thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIVjn.png)

Comment: Please provide your code so we can check it

Comment: i have added the code . check it and if u can help please do.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the "infinite scrolling" effect? An example project that could help: [Infinite Scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/). And here [a demo](https://infinite-scroll.com/demo/masonry/page3.html).

Comment: i have implemented scroll . for your reference i have added the images .

Comment: its not about scroll its just that elements can even be removed from div as u can see in the images so after elements gets removed the scroll thumb disappears and i cannot scroll further on that div

Answer (score 0):

Please use overflow hidden until the mouse is over it, then make it auto. 
Please note the 16px padding assumes a scrollbar is 16px wide, and is there so the text doesn't re-wrap when the scrollbar appears

Code snippet is below

```css
        div.myautoscroll {
            height: 40em;
            width: 40em;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #444;
            margin: 3em;
        }
        div.myautoscroll:hover {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        div.myautoscroll p {
            padding-right: 16px;
        }
        div.myautoscroll:hover p {
            padding-right: 0px;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="myautoscroll">
            <p>
            This is a test for the stackoverflow question by Mathan
            </p>

            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam luctus tincidunt
            odio sit amet eleifend. Nullam mattis posuere est, ut hendrerit ipsum ultrices
            non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam hendrerit, odio at euismod fermentum, arcu
            nunc sagittis enim, eget malesuada nulla risus rhoncus massa. In in varius
            metus. Mauris consequat leo a sem pretium sodales. Cras facilisis porttitor
            ultrices. Sed ipsum metus, luctus sit amet blandit at, facilisis vel mauris.
            Morbi leo turpis, congue dignissim imperdiet eu, laoreet mattis turpis. 
            </p>
            <p>
            Etiam eu velit magna, et euismod ligula. Aenean non ligula at tortor accumsan
            blandit eget ut lacus. Vivamus commodo nunc egestas dolor sagittis rutrum
            egestas metus sagittis. Pellentesque mollis eros ut nisl auctor tincidunt. Cras
            ullamcorper ultricies arcu, id tincidunt ligula cursus eget. Ut accumsan, dolor
            et ultricies consequat, urna lacus blandit massa, nec vestibulum sapien sapien
            sed sem. Nunc mattis lorem ornare mauris viverra vel mattis mi euismod. Vivamus
            quis neque massa. Integer at est diam, vel molestie libero. Donec non ipsum non
            mauris posuere auctor. Quisque ac sapien sit amet diam elementum sagittis quis
            et urna. Maecenas adipiscing orci sed dui eleifend bibendum. 
            </p>
            <p>
            Suspendisse massa tortor, sagittis dignissim sodales vitae, porta id lorem.
            Aliquam at enim non libero consequat blandit. Nunc eleifend fermentum diam
            vitae condimentum. Aliquam molestie magna ut purus malesuada a rhoncus orci
            aliquet. Sed lacus ante, fringilla ut accumsan non, fermentum eu nibh.
            Phasellus quis nisi sem, at hendrerit eros. Proin faucibus sollicitudin
            tristique. Donec et velit magna. Sed eu dolor eu dui fermentum aliquet. Etiam
            sollicitudin egestas dui iaculis tempor. Aliquam quis mauris in augue luctus
            condimentum ut quis turpis. Donec porttitor, sapien non interdum dignissim,
            arcu nunc ullamcorper nisi, at sagittis enim nisi fringilla risus. Nulla vel
            ipsum nulla. Aliquam fringilla quam dapibus sapien mattis at ornare massa
            fringilla. Nullam sit amet lorem quis ipsum euismod imperdiet. 
            </p>
            <p>
            In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vitae urna id ipsum ornare molestie.
            Sed non urna in lectus tempor dictum non quis metus. Phasellus at dolor eget
            justo dapibus congue posuere nec dolor. Nunc hendrerit bibendum tincidunt.
            Vestibulum scelerisque enim nulla, venenatis sollicitudin dui. Donec feugiat
            condimentum velit, at ultrices felis sagittis elementum. Sed a massa massa,
            quis scelerisque sapien. Etiam non est felis, quis imperdiet diam. Aenean felis
            sapien, egestas blandit egestas non, imperdiet convallis risus. Nunc lacinia
            aliquet adipiscing. 
            </p>
            <p>
            Integer eu eleifend nulla. Duis elementum malesuada lectus at pretium. Praesent
            euismod nibh sit amet dui interdum nec interdum elit pretium. Vestibulum ante
            ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis
            molestie est eu nisi rutrum blandit. Nulla non luctus purus. Fusce fringilla,
            dolor vel ultrices sagittis, quam purus aliquet urna, ac porta lectus velit ut
            mauris. Maecenas lectus magna, imperdiet sit amet iaculis a, vestibulum nec
            est. Sed tellus nibh, suscipit ut elementum vitae, venenatis placerat nibh.
            Pellentesque mattis convallis iaculis. Fusce mauris ipsum, ullamcorper id
            porttitor eu, luctus tincidunt lectus. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam erat mi, laoreet
            nec condimentum sed, pulvinar a massa. Integer eget orci lacus, ut dapibus
            arcu. Vivamus sollicitudin libero vitae libero ullamcorper interdum. Vivamus
            egestas dignissim eleifend.
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: this doesnt help i think u didnt get the question . I just want to know how to make scrollbar thumb always visible even if there is less content inside to fill the div